# range() keeps returning empty list

Tags: python, list, range

I have a function:

```
def button_pressed():
    first_day = int(daterangeT1.get("1.0","end-1c"))
    last_day = int(daterangeT1.get("1.0","end-1c"))
    days = range(first_day, last_day)
```

So i have tried many different ways but the range() call doesn't seem to like the two variables above it. They are both integers. It is always returning an empty list when i do a print command. Simply: "[]"

Comment: I don't know what `daterangeT1.get()` is supposed to return, but it seems that you are passing the same integer value for both start and end of the range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `first_day` and `last_day` are equal (you are getting the same key from the `daterangeT1` dictionary/object), and `range(x, x)` returns an empty list.

Also note that if `daterangeT1` is indeed a dictionary, if the `'1.0'` key doesn't exist then `get` will return the string `'end-1c'` which will cause a `ValueError` when trying to convert to `int`.